# Prerender error when deploying Nuxt 3 app to Github pages using Giuhub Actions

Tags: nuxt.js, github-actions, github-pages, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to learn a little bit of CI/CD by deploying a Nuxt 3 app to Github pages using Github Actions but it always throws a prerender error on 2 of the routes in my app when Github actions runs `nuxt generate`. I tried running `nuxt generate` in my machine and there was no error whatsoever. So this issue is probably something related to Github Actions?

Here's the log from Github Actions. You can find the error near the end of the log.

```
Static HTML export with Nuxt

Run npm run generate
  npm run generate
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    GITHUB_PAGES: true

> generate
> nuxt generate

[log] Nuxi 3.6.5
[log] Nuxt 3.6.5 with Nitro 2.5.2
[warn] Using experimental payload extraction for full-static output. You can opt-out by setting `experimental.payloadExtraction` to `false`.
[info] Building client...
[info] vite v4.3.9 building for production...
[info] transforming...
[info] ✓ 143 modules transformed.
[info] rendering chunks...
[info] computing gzip size...
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/manifest.json                     3.60 kB │ gzip:  0.58 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-500.aa16ed4d.css      1.95 kB │ gzip:  0.74 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-404.23f2309d.css      3.63 kB │ gzip:  1.12 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/index.bbc96c86.css         12.13 kB │ gzip:  2.49 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/default.6c42ce1b.js         0.22 kB │ gzip:  0.19 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/index.4de762ee.js           0.26 kB │ gzip:  0.21 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/LayoutHeader.0c5ff510.js    0.30 kB │ gzip:  0.21 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/PageTwo.d35c4254.js         0.66 kB │ gzip:  0.42 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/index.9a8be0fb.js           1.01 kB │ gzip:  0.61 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/layout.a2ac6278.js          1.32 kB │ gzip:  0.67 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-500.ad8bffd3.js       1.88 kB │ gzip:  0.99 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/index.38caa40e.js           2.02 kB │ gzip:  0.95 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/pinia.6d855e92.js           3.33 kB │ gzip:  1.72 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-404.ba077f45.js       6.53 kB │ gzip:  2.91 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/index.764b2877.js          95.68 kB │ gzip: 16.14 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/entry.f95dd8db.js         144.02 kB │ gzip: 54.40 kB
[info] ✓ built in 2.79s
[success] Client built in 2810ms
[info] Building server...
[info] vite v4.3.9 building SSR bundle for production...
[info] transforming...
[info] ✓ 95 modules transformed.
[info] rendering chunks...
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/index-styles.c4f3f660.mjs            0.08 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-404-styles.cf00f4cc.mjs        0.15 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-500-styles.a001b7ed.mjs        0.15 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/styles.mjs                                 0.44 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/index-e12b288f.js                    0.22 kB │ map:   5.28 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/default-dc738482.js                  1.06 kB │ map:   0.13 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/island-renderer-111fb402.js          1.11 kB │ map:   1.43 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/LayoutHeader-747fd40b.js             1.18 kB │ map:   0.14 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/index-cb071b83.js                    1.61 kB │ map:   0.14 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-500-styles-1.mjs-0a86f27a.js   2.17 kB │ map:   0.12 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/PageTwo-95ad2d12.js                  2.31 kB │ map:   1.06 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/index-3a419ccf.js                    2.63 kB │ map:   1.99 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-500-90d6b764.js                3.10 kB │ map:   3.78 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/layout-fe23ec6d.js                   3.33 kB │ map:   7.04 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/index-9e1c42d7.js                    3.47 kB │ map:   3.65 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-404-styles-1.mjs-6ef6e240.js   3.86 kB │ map:   0.12 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-404-1f4e83a5.js                9.75 kB │ map:  18.91 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/index-styles-1.mjs-bfad4fc1.js      12.38 kB │ map:   0.11 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs                                33.74 kB │ map:  79.34 kB
[info] .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/index-429347c0.js                   97.95 kB │ map: 107.00 kB
[info] ✓ built in 1.62s
[success] Server built in 1634ms
[success] [nitro] Generated public .output/public
[info] [nitro] Initializing prerenderer
[info] [nitro] Prerendering 7 initial routes with crawler
[log] [nitro]   ├─ /PageTwo (65ms)
[log] [nitro]   ├─ /sample-page (62ms)
[log] [nitro]   ├─ /pinia-test (82ms) (Error: [500] )
[log] [nitro]   ├─ /users (83ms) (Error: [500] )
[log] [nitro]   ├─ /200.html (63ms)
[log] [nitro]   ├─ /404.html (63ms)
[log] [nitro]   ├─ / (81ms)
[log] [nitro]   ├─ /PageTwo/_payload.json (1ms)
[log] [nitro]   ├─ /sample-page/_payload.json (1ms)
[log] [nitro]   ├─ /_payload.json (1ms)
[log] [nitro] 
Errors prerendering:
[log] [nitro]   ├─ /pinia-test (500)
[log] [nitro]   ├─ /users (500)
[log] [nitro]
Error:  Exiting due to prerender errors.
  at prerender (node_modules/nitropack/dist/shared/nitro.1db3349c.mjs:189:11)
  at async node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:2641:7
  at async build (node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:3794:5)
  at async Object.invoke (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/build.mjs:59:5)
  at async Object.invoke (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/generate.mjs:36:5)
  at async _main (node_modules/nuxi/dist/cli.mjs:49:20)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

And here's the workflow file that Github Actions recommended.

```
# Sample workflow for building and deploying a Nuxt site to GitHub Pages
#
# To get started with Nuxt see: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/installation
#
name: Deploy Nuxt site to Pages

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: ["main"]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow only one concurrent deployment, skipping runs queued between the run in-progress and latest queued.
# However, do NOT cancel in-progress runs as we want to allow these production deployments to complete.
concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: false

jobs:
  # Build job
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Detect package manager
        id: detect-package-manager
        run: |
          if [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/yarn.lock" ]; then
            echo "manager=yarn" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "command=install" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            exit 0
          elif [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/package.json" ]; then
            echo "manager=npm" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "command=ci" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            exit 0
          else
            echo "Unable to determine package manager"
            exit 1
          fi
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "18"
          cache: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }}
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v3
        with:
          # Automatically inject router.base in your Nuxt configuration file and set
          # target to static (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-target/).
          #
          # You may remove this line if you want to manage the configuration yourself.
          static_site_generator: nuxt
      - name: Restore cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: |
            dist
            .nuxt
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nuxt-build-${{ hashFiles('dist') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nuxt-build-
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }} ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.command }}
      - name: Static HTML export with Nuxt
        run: npm run generate
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v2
        with:
          path: ./dist

  # Deployment job
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v2
```

Comment: try to add `nitro: {
        prerender:{
            failOnError:false,
        }
    }` to nuxt.config.ts

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim It still throws the error.